# how to load csv file content to mysql database and avoid duplicate entry?

Tags: php, mysql, database

What I was trying to do is to load a csv file into the database. But I am having a problem because of duplicate entry.

I am using PHP script to load the file.

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $target_path;
        $sql.= "' INTO TABLE dummy ";   
        $sql.= "COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','";
        $sql.= "OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'";
        $sql.= "ESCAPED BY '\"'";
        $sql.= "LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
        $sql.= "IGNORE 1 LINES;";
```

Database Table Structure:

```
id | firstname | lastname
```

CSV File content..

```
id | firstname | lastname

1  John Doe
2  James Carry
3  Luke Borrow
```

As expected 'id' is the primary key. Is there a way to skip values that violates primary key constraint on the fly?

Comment: @skrilled: there is no `ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax for `LOAD DATA INFILE`, it's not a regular `INSERT` query. Even on `INSERT` queries, you could just use `INSERT IGNORE ` if you don't plan to update anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'somefile' IGNORE
```

[From the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

> If you specify IGNORE, input rows that duplicate an existing row on a unique key value are skipped.